# EC2 with Cloudflare

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, cloudflare

I have an EC2 Ubuntu instance with the Cloudflare's nameservers. It's a Django app. The instance is running nginx and supervisor gunicorn.
[image]

The instance has a security group with the IPs range from Cloudflare. These inbound rules are for port 443 only because I have an SSL certificate:
[image]

This is my django.conf:
[image]

After a test my certificate is not working:
[image]

And I cannot access my webpage:
[image]

I need help, please. Probably is something obvious but I don't understand.